# Filter dropdown not working when selected an item

Tags: javascript, html

My project is trying to do a dropdown filter and when I select a certain item like soccer in the dropdown it doesn't come up showing that athlete in the specific item selected. Below is the code for my javascript filtering and [my image is supposed to show the soccer player since that was the filter selected][1]. and my HTML is below also for how it is displayed

````
//returns the value of selected value and filters the athleteList by the selected dropdown and value 
    filterObj.selectedValue = function(anchorObj) {
        console.log("Selected Value: " + anchorObj.id);

        //This is used to set the initial value of valueLabel
        //If (anchorObj.id === undefined) is true the operator returns the value of the first expression 
        //If it's false it returns the value of the second expression
        valueLabel = (anchorObj.id === undefined) ? "" : (": " + anchorObj.id);

        //Calls the filterLabel function and sets it's parameters to the user selected dropdown and filter value
        filterLabel(dropdownLabel, valueLabel);

        //The switch takes the activeFilter as a parameter which was assigned a value in the selectedDropDown function 
        //The if statement parameters check if the user selected "All-Sports" if thats the value the user
        //selected filterFn remains null since those options are made to display everything
        //The function will only return true when the object in the array has a key/value pair that matches the filter
        //For example if we select the Sport and then Soccer, Sport is key and Soccer is our value so the object
        //has a Sport key equal to Soccer it will return true
        var filterFn = null;
        switch (activeFilter) {
            case "Sport":
                if (anchorObj.id === "All-Sports") {
                    filterFn = null;
                    break
                }
                filterFn = function (c) {
                    return anchorObj.id === c.sport;
                };
        }

        //The switch statement returns two possible types of values. It's either set to null or to the value of a function that returns/sets a value of true
        //or false for every elements in the array
        //The ternary operator is used to set the value of filteredAthletes
        //If filterFn is not null is true the first statment executes, otherwise the second statement executes
        //The first statement takes the athletesList, which is the object list, applies the filter method to it with the parameter filterFn
        //The second statement returns the unfiltered athleteList
        //The filter method takes every object in filterFn that returned true and those are the only objects stored in the filterAthletes array
        var filteredAthletes = filterFn ? athleteList.filter(filterFn) : athleteList;
        console.log(filteredAthletes);

        //The final step is to display the filteredAthletes
        //We do this by setting the innerHTML value of our div with id listHere to  ${filteredAthletes.map(athleteTemplate).join("") which
        //returns a new array (maps) with the specific elements referenced in the athleteTemplate function and joins them to a string seperated by a space
        document.getElementById("listHere").innerHTML = `
            ${filteredAthletes.map(athleteTemplate).join("")}
        `;
    };

    //Called to display unfiltered list
    filterObj.selectedValue({});

    //Athlete template (keep in this file because its referenced by the function above) pulic method
    //This is a basic template for displaying array of objects on your HTML page
    //This can be manipulated and changed to fit the requirements/parameters of your array of objects
    //This template requires two things to be displayed, a div in the HTML code and a to be added to the document using the div's id
    //The code snippet that adds this template to its designated div on the HTML page is in the function below
    //<div class="column"><div class = "content"><a href="${athlete.url}" target="_blank"> 
    function athleteTemplate(athlete) {
        return `
       <div class = "content">
            <img src="${athlete.image}">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="text"> 
                        <h3>${athlete.athleteName}</h3>
                        Born: ${athlete.birthday} <br><br>
                        Age: ${athlete.age} <br><br>
                        Sport: ${athlete.sport} <br><br>
                        <a href="${athlete.url}" target="_blank">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                
        `;
    }```

//html
<body>
        <div class ="dropContainer">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button title="Sport" onclick="filter.myFunction(); filter.selectedDropDown()" class="dropbtn">Sports</button>
                <div id="Sport" class="dropdown-content">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="myInput2" onkeyup="filter.filterFunction('myInput2')">
                    <a id="All-Sports" onclick="filter.selectedValue(this)" href="#all">Show All</a>
                    <a id="Soccer" onclick="filter.selectedValue(this)" href="#Soccer">Soccer</a>
                    <a id="Basketball" onclick="filter.selectedValue(this)" href="#Basketball">Basketball</a>
                    <a id="Football" onclick="filter.selectedValue(this)" href="#Football">Football</a>
                    <a id="Baseball" onclick="filter.selectedValue(this)" href="#Baseball">Baseball</a>
                    <a id="Golf" onclick="filter.selectedValue(this)" href="#Golf">Golf</a>
                    <a id="Tennis" onclick="filter.selectedValue(this)" href="#Tennis">Tennis</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>       
        <center>
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Dropdown Filter with Image Overlay</h1>
                <h2>Select the 'Sports' menu and select an option to filter the list by. <br>
                    Use the Search Bar to filter the dropdown. <br>
                    Hover over the images for more information on the athlete. <br>
                    Click 'Learn More' to go to their Wiki page.</h2>
                <h2>Current Filter:</h2>
                <div class="filter" id='filteredBy'></div>
            </div>

            <div class="wrapper" id="listHere"></div>
        </center>

        <script src="js/athletes.js"></script>
        <script src="js/MakeFilter.js"></script>
        <script> 
            var athleteList = getAthleteList();
            var filter = MakeFilter("Sport", "Filter", "myInput2", athleteList);                  
        </script>
    </body>


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIHKA.jpg
````

Comment: Please create JSFiddle

Comment: here is the fiddle for above https://jsfiddle.net/39s8d6og/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work.